# jQuery if data-id element hasClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, if-statement, show-hide

I don't know if the function i am trying to create is missing an element or if I am missing something but my function isn't working at all. Not sure if am missing something or if i am not adding something. let me know I provided jQuery and screenshot of the code i am trying to get to work. Basically what i am trying to do is if a certain element that has a data-id has a certain class then hide certain list-items.

```
$(function($){
    if( $('.chbs-vehicle[data-id="313"] a').hasClass('chbs-state-selected') ){
        $('ul.chbs-list-reset li(1)').hide();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: `$('ul.chbs-list-reset li(1)')` is not valid.  Either use a valid css selector for nth-child or nth-of-type or something, or use `$('ul.chbs-list-reset li').eq(0)`

Comment: doesn't work. i added $('ul.chbs-list-reset li').eq(0)

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log inside the if to verify that it is evaluating to true?  From your picture it should, but that is dependent upon it being like that on page load.

Comment: yes i did and i even added an alert but nothing pops up.

Comment: How is the `chbs-state-selected` class being added?

Comment: it's added dynamically via that plug-in's jquery once user clicks "select"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li(1)` isn't a valid expression and you should use a different evaluator:

```
$('ul.chbs-list-reset li:eq(0)')
$('ul.chbs-list-reset li:first-child')
$('ul.chbs-list-reset li').eq(0)
```

Take a look at this <kbd>[Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/ZxvbYv)</kbd>

If your condition is met on page load, it works just fine. However, if the `chbs-state-selected` class is added dynamically, you need to listen for that change with an event handler. Your script as you have it doesn't constantly poll the document to see if `Vehicle 313`'s `a` has the class.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you need to listen for that same click event that adds the `chbs-state-selected` class. Check out this rudimentary <kbd>[Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/xWpwrB)</kbd>.

Given this, you don't necessarily need to check for the class, just attach the `hide/show` functions to the same event. However, if necessary you can add the `hasClass` check to it.

Regardless, it should be inside that same handler that adds the `chbs-state-selected` in the first place

Comment: that makes a whole lot of sense now. I did that but still didn't work :-/

Comment: http://staging.idgadvertising.com/10milemovers/wp-content/themes/tenmilemovers-child/custom.js?ver=1 just so you can see the JS file and the actual link to the webpage is this [link]http://staging.idgadvertising.com/10milemovers/book-now/

Comment: Pasting the code I gave you into the console allows it to work. note that it hides the wrong element I believe, there are a few `chbs-list-reset` elements, so you may need to preface that with a selector like `.chbs-booking-extra-list`

Comment: it didn't work still. logically and seeing what you are doing..i know it should work but I don't know why

Comment: would it work if it instead of the '.on' we used the '.click' ?

Comment: nevermind that still didn't work. I think there is something conflicting but i might have to just move forward with out this for now until I can figure out something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eq:  jquery function

```
 $(function($){
        if( $('.chbs-vehicle[data-id="313"] a').hasClass('chbs-state-selected') ){
            $('ul.chbs-list-reset li:eq(0)').hide();
        }
    });
```